# Messaging API client function with many possible parameters

Tags: python

I'm working an open source project written in Python that is a wrapper to the [Pushover API](https://pushover.net/api) called [py_pushover](https://github.com/KronosKoderS/py_pushover).

The main function of this wrapper is the `push_message` function which allows the user to push a notification.  The API has 10 possible parameters with only 3 being required.  I've handled those three required with named parameters and the optional parameters using `kwargs`.  Is this the most pythonic way of handling a large amount of parameters?

**push_message from [py_pushover](https://github.com/KronosKoderS/py_pushover)/[py_pushover](https://github.com/KronosKoderS/py_pushover/tree/master/py_pushover)/[message.py](https://github.com/KronosKoderS/py_pushover/blob/master/py_pushover/message.py.)**

```
def push_message(token, user, message, **kwargs):
    """
    Send message to selected user/group/device.
    :param str token: application token
    :param str user: user or group id to send the message to
    :param str message: your message
    :param str title: your message's title, otherwise your app's name is used
    :param str device: your user's device name to send the message directly to that device
    :param list device: your user's devices names to send the message directly to that device
    :param str url: a supplementary URL to show with your message
    :param str url_title: a title for your supplementary URL, otherwise just the URL is shown
    :param int priority: message priority (Use the Priority class to select)
    :param int retry: how often (in seconds) the Pushover servers will retry the notification to the user (required
                      only with priority level of Emergency)
    :param int expire: how many seconds your notification will continue to be retried (required only with priority
                       level of Emergency)
    :param datetime timestamp: a datetime object repr the timestamp of your message's date and time to display to the user
    :param str sound: the name of the sound to override the user's default sound choice (Use the Sounds consts to
                      select)
    :param bool html: Enable rendering message on user device using HTML
    """
    data_out = {
        'token': token,
        'user': user,  # can be a user or group key
        'message': message
    }

    # Support for non-required parameters of PushOver
    if 'title' in kwargs:
        data_out['title'] = kwargs['title']
    if 'device' in kwargs:
        temp = kwargs['device']
        if type(temp) == list:
            data_out['device'] = ','.join(temp)
        else:
            data_out['device'] = temp
        data_out['device'] = kwargs['device']
    if 'url' in kwargs:
        data_out['url'] = kwargs['url']
    if 'url_title' in kwargs:
        data_out['url_title'] = kwargs['url_title']
    if 'priority' in kwargs:
        data_out['priority'] = kwargs['priority']

        # Emergency prioritized messages require 'retry' and 'expire' to be defined
        if data_out['priority'] == PRIORITIES.EMERGENCY:
            if 'retry' not in kwargs:
                raise TypeError('Missing `retry` argument required for message priority of Emergency')
            else:
                retry_val = kwargs['retry']

                # 'retry' val must be a minimum of _MIN_RETRY and max of _MAX_EXPIRE
                if not (_MIN_RETRY <= retry_val <= _MAX_EXPIRE):
                    raise ValueError('`retry` argument must be at a minimum of {} and a maximum of {}'.format(
                        _MIN_RETRY, _MAX_EXPIRE
                    ))

                data_out['retry'] = retry_val
            if 'expire' not in kwargs:
                raise TypeError('Missing `expire` arguemnt required for message priority of Emergency')
            else:
                expire_val = kwargs['expire']

                # 'expire' val must be a minimum of _MIN_RETRY and max of _MAX_EXPIRE
                if not(_MIN_RETRY <= expire_val <= _MAX_EXPIRE):
                    raise ValueError('`expire` argument must be at a minimum of {} and a maximum of {}'.format(
                        _MIN_RETRY, _MAX_EXPIRE
                    ))

                data_out['expire'] = expire_val

            # Optionally a callback url may be supplied for the Emergency Message
            if 'callback' in kwargs:
                data_out['callback'] = kwargs['callback']

    if 'timestamp' in kwargs:
        data_out['timestamp'] = int(time.mktime(kwargs['timestamp'].timetuple()))
    if 'sound' in kwargs:
        data_out['sound'] = kwargs['sound']
    if 'html' in kwargs:
        data_out['html'] = int(kwargs['html'])

    return send(_push_url, data_out=data_out)
```

**send from [py_pushover](https://github.com/KronosKoderS/py_pushover)/[py_pushover](https://github.com/KronosKoderS/py_pushover/tree/master/py_pushover)/[_base.py](https://github.com/KronosKoderS/py_pushover/blob/master/py_pushover/_base.py)**

```
def send(url, data_out=None, get_method=False):
    """
    Sends a request to the selected url with the payload `data_out`.  Set `get_method` to True to send as a GET request.
    Default request is a POST.
    :param str url: url to send the request to
    :param dict data_out: payload data to send
    :param bool get_method: True = GET request; False = POST request (default)
    :return dict: a dictionary with the json results of the request.
    """
    if get_method:
        res = requests.get(url, params=data_out)
    else:
        res = requests.post(url, params=data_out)

    res.raise_for_status()

    ret_dict = res.json()
    if 'X-Limit-App-Limit' in res.headers:
        ret_dict['app_limit'] = res.headers['X-Limit-App-Limit']
    if 'X-Limit-App-Remaining' in res.headers:
        ret_dict['app_remaining'] = res.headers['X-Limit-App-Remaining']
    if 'X-Limit-App-Reset' in res.headers:
        ret_dict['app_reset'] = res.headers['X-Limit-App-Reset']

    return ret_dict
```

**Note:** In order for this code to run properly you'll need to supply an app token and user/group id which is obtained from the Pushover site.  Creating an application is free, but registering a device to send a message to isn't.  There is, however, a free trial period of 7 days.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever seeing repeated constructions I feel the urge to refactor it into `for` loop, and in your case you have a lot of repeating stuff similar to:

> ```
> if 'title' in kwargs:
>     data_out['title'] = kwargs['title']
> ```

This can be simplified to:

```
for parameter in ('title', 'device', 'url', 'url_title', 'priority', 
                  'retry', 'expire', 'callback', 'timestamp',
                  'sound', 'html'):
    if parameter in kwargs:
        data_out[parameter] = kwargs[parameter]
```

You could even extract the entire list into a constant outside of the function, and make it even neater.

Now that you've gathered all the data from `kwargs`, you could continue doing the validation of the parameters.

```
if type(data_out.get('device')) == list:
    data_out['device'] = ','.join(data_out['device']

if data_out.get('priority') == PRIORITIES.EMERGENCY:
   retry_val = data_out.get('retry')

   if retry_val is None:
      raise ValueError('Need retry value....')
   else:
      if not ( _MIN_RETRY <= retry_val <= _MAX_EXPIRE ):
         raise ValueError('Retry not in range')
   ...
```

You'll get the gist. The main idea here is to first transfer all of the parameters, then validate them afterwards. By using `get()` we avoid doing the exception catching needed if the key doesn't exists, which could be useful in your case.

I would also do a similar change to the transformations in your `send()` function:

```
HEADER_TO_DICT = {
   'X-Limit-App-Limit' : 'app_limit',
   'X-Limit-App-Remaining' : 'app_remaining'
   'X-Limit-App-Reset' : 'app_reset'
}

# For Python 3, use HEADER_TO_DICT.items()
for header, dict_value in HEADER_TO_DICT.iteritems():   
    if header in res.headers:
        ret_dict[dict_value] = res.headers[header]
```

Other than this your coding style seems to match PEP8 nicely, and is OK to read and understand. If you want to make the previous `for` loop independent of Python version, you should read ["Iterating over dictionaries using for loops in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/1548472), and if not happy with any of those solutions, go back to the following variant:

```
for header in HEADER_TO_DICT:
    if header in res.headers:
        ret_dict[HEADER_TO_DICT[header]] = res.headers[header]
```

<sub>**Disclaimer:** Code is somewhat untested :-)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You're using `type(data_out.get('device')) == list`, but it's actually recommended that you don't use this approach because it isn't reliable. It only tests against direct type identity. That means that it wouldn't work for subclasses.

Here's a simple example showing `Counter`, which inherits from dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> type(counter) == dict
False
>>> isinstance(counter, dict)
True
```

What's happening here is that Python sees that `counter`'s type is `Counter`, not `dict`. *However* `Counter` inherits from `dict`, so `counter` is an *instance* of `dict`, meaning that the latter does evaluate as true.

Usually inheritance is fine for your purposes as classes should inherit most of the same functionality. `Counter`s can still have values assigned and accessed the same way a `dict` can.

So in your case it's likely that your code will run regardless of whether the value is actually a `list` or just something that inherits from it.